# Can I revert to my previous version app in iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

I have app in App Store, I submitted version 1.1, after Apple reviewed, approved and published it, I noticed there is a clear major bug, so I had to suspend my app from App Store.

I submitted a new version 1.2, you know it would take 5-7 days to be reviewed and published, can I revert to my previous version app (1.0) while the new version is released?

Answer (score 15):

Actually there is just one way :

Set the availability date for **buggy** version to far future, then submit new version and ask for a expedited review.
After these you should have new version reviewed under 48 hours, depending on weekday.

Open the app in iTunes Connect and click "Rights and Pricing" top right. You get a message like this: "You have selected an Available Date in the future. This will remove your currently live version from the App Store until the new date. Changing Available Date affects all versions of the application, both Ready For Sale and In Review."

Also you can request a faster review for your next update:
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/?topic=expedite

Comment: But how can someone change the availability of an already published update?

Comment: @alex-i Open the app in iTunes Connect and click "Rights and Pricing" top right. It looks like this is working: "You have selected an Available Date in the future. This will remove your currently live version from the App Store until the new date. Changing Available Date affects all versions of the application, both Ready For Sale and In Review."

Comment: It does no longer work, iTunes connect automatically set the date to "today" when you specify a date in the future. Instead, simply add a new version and when you select "ready to upload" indicate that there was a serious usability issue and you will be prompted to select the version which will be removed from appstore downloads

Comment: This doesn't work. Setting the date to the future just removes the app from the store. It does not revert the currently selling app to the previous version.

Comment: @christophe, your solution didn't work for me either. Checking the buggy version as "significant usability issue" did note remove the currently selling buggy version to the previous version. I think this will only apply when the new fixed version goes live.

Comment: @TomKincaid you right, version is not removed. And Apple does not speed up validation of your new release when you say the current one has a serious usability issue. We are all screwed.

Answer (score 7):

No sadly you cannot according to **Apple**, here's an excerpt from the iTunes Connect FAQ :

> **Question: The new version of my app on the App Store has a bug. Can I use a previous version to replace it?**
>
> No. You cannot revert to a previous version on the App Store. You must submit a new version.

Source : [iTunes Connect FAQ](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Managing%20Published%20Apps#11310557))

Comment: is it still can not revert back to the previous version these days? after 8 years of this question?

Comment: It's really a shame. On top of that, you need to wait for Apple to review a new build for at least a day even if you request an expedited review.

Answer (score 3):

So, It is quite clear that we can't revert to the previous version on the App Store and the only solution is to submit a new version to the store. But We can fasten up the reviewing process  by requesting the Expedited reviews. please go to the link([Expedited Review Form](https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/?topic=expedite)) and Fill up the form.